# Elm syntax help required

Tags: elm

Could you please explain me what does mean in Elm next statement?

```
(=>) = (,)
```

I found it in the example of [Elm architecture tutorial](https://github.com/evancz/elm-architecture-tutorial/tree/master/examples/7)

Comment: Hi, actually I figured out myself just by playing with the example. But anyway thanks for the answer, it is quite helpful!

Comment: can you mark the question closed then

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is infix notation. In effect, this defines a function

```
(=>) = \a b -> (a,b)
```

Infix is then used without the brackets, so

```
a => b == (a,b)
```